# Capistrano: Network unreachable error, but can ssh to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano

I'm setting up Capistrano 3 with a new server so I can deploy a Rails application and am currently stuck. Whenever I run any `cap production` task, this happens:

```
$ cap production deploy:setup
cap aborted!
Errno::ENETUNREACH: Network is unreachable - connect(2) for [IPv6addresshere]:22
```

I've spent a couple hours trying to figure this out and am not sure what's going on. I can ssh as the same user Capistrano is using without a password because I have the authorized key setup. Also, from the remote server, I can `ssh git@github.com` fine because I have the deploy key configured.

Any suggestions?

Here is the trace:

```
/home/awatt/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:64:in `connect'
/home/awatt/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:64:in `connect_internal'
/home/awatt/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:139:in `connect'
/home/awatt/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:636:in `block in tcp'
/home/awatt/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:231:in `each'
/home/awatt/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:231:in `foreach'
/home/awatt/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:626:in `tcp'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `initialize'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:232:in `new'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:232:in `start'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:155:in `with_ssh'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:108:in `execute_command'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:55:in `test'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-rbenv-2.0.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/rbenv.rake:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/home/awatt/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rbenv:validate
```

Comment: Are you sshing in your tests via IPv6 as well ?

Comment: try `ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true`

Comment: @Doon Good point. I just tried ssh'ing via IPv6 and it won't work. How can I force Capistrano to use IPv4? Curiously, if I change `ssh_options[:user]` from `deploy` (a new-ish deploy user) to another username, I don't get this error — but I do need to use the deploy user. Again, regular `ssh deploy@myserver` works from my machine.

@SeanHuber Thanks, I'm doing that already.

Comment: Also, the IP it says is unreachable is not one the one for my server. This is failing during my `rbenv:validate` step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had correctly configured my `deploy.rb` file but neglected to update `deploy/production.rb`, which had a user configured as `deploy@example.com`. So after a deploy step ran in the primary configuration file, it would attempt the same step based on the production settings, and fail to obtain an SSH connection. It was something simple after all! Thanks to those who commented.